# Why is My program Login Looping? (Python)

Tags: python

Hello i am trying to get a login system working using text files where it reads the password from there but i get an infinity loop?

My Code:

```
inFile = open('passwords.txt', 'r')

print("Welcome To Kellys")
print("This is the admin panel.")
print("You will now be asked for An Admin password.")
print("_____________________________________________________________________________")
print("Would You like to Login(1), Signup(2)")
logindecis = input("Decision: ")
if logindecis == '1':
    ask2 = ("What is Your password?: ")
elif logindecis == '2':
    asknewpass = input("Create A password now: ")
    f = open("passwords.txt","w")
    f.write(asknewpass)
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()

else:
    print("Wrong")


# Login bit
login_check = False
while login_check != True:
    if ask2 in inFile:
        print("Logged in")
        login_check = True
    else:
        ask2 = input("What is Your Password: ")


menu_on=True
while menu_on == True:
    create_stock_table()
    create_time_table()
    create_user_table()
    print("------------------------------------------")
    print("|  To Look at the Menu press 1.          |")
    print("|  To calculate pay press 2.             |")
    print("|  To Look at the opening hours press 3. |")
    print("|  To add new customer details press 4.  |")
    print("|  To log out press 5.                   |")
    print("|  To configure DB press 10.             |")
    print("|  To Email us Press 7.                  |")
    print("------------------------------------------")
```

My Display:

```
Would You like to Login(1), Signup(2)
Decision: 2
Create A password now: leighton
What is Your Password: leighton
What is Your Password: leighton
What is Your Password:
```

or if i press 1:

```
Would You like to Login(1), Signup(2)
Decision: 1
What is Your Password: leighton
What is Your Password: leighton
What is Your Password: leighton
```

i dont actually see what is wrong here so i need a second pair of eyes to help this problem

Comment: `if ask2 in inFile and asknewpass in inFile:` -- when are both those conditions going to be true?

Comment: You don't alter `asknewpass` in your `while login_check != True:` loop, so if the condition `asknewpass in inFile` is false, it can never become true.

Comment: oh yes i see that. ive just changed it to  if ask2 in inFile: and stil getting loop

Comment: I don't think `... in inFile` is ever going to be true when `inFile` is a file object.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to do

```
inFile = open('passwords.txt', 'r')
content = inFile.read()

login_check = False
while login_check != True:
    if ask2 in content and asknewpass in content:
        # ...
```

Comment: @DJLeightonz Just try moving it out of the the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Original loop:

```
login_check = False
while login_check != True:
    if ask2 in inFile and asknewpass in inFile:
        print("Logged in")
        login_check = True
    else:
        ask2 = input("What is Your Password: ")
```

Your code loops until `login_check` is `True`, and the only way that happens is if `ask2` and `asknewpass` are in `inFile`.  But `asknewpass` only gets set if you pick option `2`.  If you pick option `1`, `asknewpass in inFile` will always be `False`, so it will loop forever.  Remove the check for `asknewpass in inFile`, like this:

```
    if ask2 in inFile:
        print("Logged in")
        login_check = True
```